# Jest test component's inner method

Tags: reactjs, react-native, testing, jestjs

I'm using react native 0.40 with jest 20. When trying to test the inner method of a component I fail because I cannot get the instance of it and then call the method.

For example I can test the rendered component using the snapshots like

```
it('renders correctly', () => {
    var store = mockStore(initialState);

    const tree = renderer.create(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App/>
        </Provider>
    ).toJSON()

    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

But if I try to test an inner method of the App component I don't find any way to access it.
So the following code will not run

```
it("checks version number correctly", () => {
    var store = mockStore(initialState);

    const tree = renderer.create(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App/>
        </Provider>
    )

    expect(tree.needsUpdate("1.0.0")).toBe(true)
})
```

The solution some people used was "react-test-renderer/shallow" or "enzyme" to shallow render the component and access the inner method, but the first one cannot be found when I import it (maybe related to RN version?) and enzyme cannot be installed properly (maybe again, a dependency issue). So what I wonder is, what's the best way to test an inner method.

Comment: Can you update your answer with an example?

Comment: Your question, sorry.

Comment: Ok thanks, Can I see the code of the App component? Thanks

Comment: To be honest is very simple, it's just a class extending Component that renders either a Navigator component is the method needsUpdate return false, and an error message if the app needs to be updated. This is why I need to test the needsUpdate method, at the moment it checks just if the version number of the app is newer than a reference value.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to actually wrap your component in a provider. If you just want to test your component, you can export it without `connect()()`. For instance:

```
export class App extends React.Component {
   // your things
}

export default connect()(App);
```

Inside your test file, you can import your app like so:

```
import ConnectedApp, { App } from "../App";
```

Then when you want to test your encapsulated `App`, you can treat it like any other standard component:

```
const props = {
  // mocked-out props your store would provide
};
const component = shallow(<App {...props} />);
component.instance().whateverMethodYouWant();
```

Personally, I never wrap a component in a mock provider unless I need to `render` and deeper components are `connect`ed.